# Using Linq, I get this: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
IEnumerable<OfficeView> allOffices = GetAllOffices(); //this method also uses some linq query
foreach (var office in allOffices)
{
    officeSales.Add(
             new Tuple<int, decimal>(office.Id, GetSaleAmount(office.Id, someParams)));
}


public decimal GetAgentSaleAmount(int officeRef, someTypes someParams)
{
    var q = ObjectQuery.Where
                (i => i.officeId == officeRef && i.someOtherStuff == someParams)
                .ToList();

    return q.Sum(i => i.NetPrice);
}
```

I can't set `MultipleActiveResultSets = true`. Instead, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921821/error-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-mu), I tried to do `.ToList()` before doing the summation, but got the same error. (and even if I wouldn't get the error, I think it would cause heavy load to fetch everything just to get the summation of one field)

I will be super thankful for any suggestion to solve this problem!

**Update:** The problem was all about `GetAllOffices()`, which returned `IEnumerable` (which leaves the `DataReader` open). I changed the first line as below and it worked. Thanks a lot guys :)

```
IEnumerable<OfficeView> allOffices = GetAllOffices().ToList();
```

Comment: why can't you set Multiple Active Results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error said that reader is already opened, that means that you have run some query before which needs to close.
Write `.ToList()` to that linq query and do same for other queries too.

Comment: And what about other queries?

Comment: no other query is being ran :(
apparently, the problem is not with `sum`, I removed sum, and still get the error.. going to explore it more, thanks

Comment: Do you have just one `Where` or you have other operations or more then one `Where`?

Comment: just one where, but lots of conditions in it

Comment: Try to do `.ToList()` after first condition

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do both **adding** and **querying** at the same time.You need to finish adding "Sale" object to "Sales" collection before trying to calculate the sales value.

In other words, you cannot query until the transaction is committed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried separating them, still no success. But the problem is not with the query in `GetSaleAgentAmount` either, since I'm using it somewhere else and works fine. 

I have `IEnimerable<whatever> allOffices = GetAllOffices()`, which uses linq, and works fine in other parts of the projects, but I am suspecting something may be wrong with iterating on `allOffices` and using `linq` inside it. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: Please post your complete code. where have you initialized your entity model? You need to use "using (var dbcontxt = new MyEntities()){} if you have not used it.

Comment: Problem was `GetAllOffices()`. Did `GetAllOffices().ToList()` and it solved the problem. Thanks.